# python 3 requests_futures requests to same server in different processes

Tags: parallel-processing, python-requests, python-3.5

I am looking into parallelization of url requests onto one single webserver in python for the first time. 
I would like to use `requests_futures` for this task as it seems that one can really split up processes onto several cores with the `ProcessPoolExecutor`. 
The example code from the module documentation is:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

session = FuturesSession(executor=ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2))

future_one = session.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
future_two = session.get('http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar')
response_one = future_one.result()
print('response one status: {0}'.format(response_one.status_code))
print(response_one.content)
response_two = future_two.result()
print('response two status: {0}'.format(response_two.status_code))
print(response_two.content)
```

The above code works for me, however, I need some help with getting it customized to my needs.

1. I want to query the same server, let's say, 50 times (e.g. 50 different httpbin.org/get?... requests). What would be a good way to split these up onto different futures other than just defining `future_one`, ...`_two` and so on?
2. I am thinking about using different processes. According to the module documentation, it should be just a change in the first three lines of the above code:

   ```py
   from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
   from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

   session = FuturesSession(executor=ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2))
   ```

   If I execute this I get the following error:

   ```
   concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
   ```

   How do I get this running properly?